# How to vectorize a for loop with conditions instead of iterating over a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

I have some code that ingests two .csv files: *employee.csv and schedule.csv*. The employee.csv has properties '**ID**' and '**Building**' which I use together as a '**key**' to gather entries in the schedule file with the same ID/Building pair based on conditionals.

At the end I am left with a list of lists that I use to create the output dataframe.

employees.csv

```
Name,Date,Building,ID,Start Time,Stop Time,Duration,Years,EmployeeType,Status
1,3/1/2021,1,1,22:04:05,0:00:00,1:55:55,21,EmployeeType1,Status
1,3/1/2021,2,2,17:04:05,0:00:00,5:55:55,21,EmployeeType1,Status
```

schedule.csv

```
Name,Rev,Building,ID,Op Date,Start Time,Dur,WorkType
1,1,1,1,3/1/2021,23:04:12,1,WorkType1
1,1,1,1,3/1/2021,23:44:00,1,WorkType1
```

Dummy code (the data logic may not make perfect sense, but it mirrors what I am trying to do):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


# takes sequence and converts
def convert_sequence(seq):
    return ''.join(seq)


def create_output(employee_file, schedule_file, output_file):
    output_columns = ['Name', 'Date', 'Building', 'ID', 'Years', 'Type', 'Start Time', 'Stop Time', 'Duration',
                      'SumDuration', '%Time', 'Gap', 'Sequence', 'MinDuration', 'MaxDuration', 'Status']

    employee_df = pd.read_csv(employee_file)
    schedule = pd.read_csv(schedule_file)

    output_data_list = []
    # loop through rows in employees, get pairs as keys to search through schedule
    for iw_index, iw_row in employee_df.iterrows():
        employee_name = iw_row['Name']
        date = iw_row['Date']
        building = iw_row['Building']
        id = iw_row['ID']
        start = iw_row['Start Time']
        end = iw_row['Stop Time']
        duration = iw_row['Duration']
        num_years = iw_row['Years']
        employee_type = iw_row['EmployeeType']
        status = iw_row['Status']

        # if we don't find any rows that match on the id/building, still write out a row for the employee we are on
        # with current data we have
        if len(list(schedule.loc[(schedule['Building'] == building) & (schedule['ID'] == id)].iterrows())) == 0:
            data_retrieved = [employee_name, date, building, id, num_years, employee_type, start, end, duration,
                              'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', status]
            output_data_list.append(data_retrieved)
            # skip gathering rest of data because we won't find any matches, move to next pair
            print('skipping')
            continue

        # holds list of contact types for this particular building/id pair
        work_sequence = schedule.loc[(schedule['Building'] == building) & (schedule['ID'] == id)]['WorkType'].tolist()
        work_sequence_converted = convert_sequence(work_sequence)

        # get all durations for this pair
        durations = schedule.loc[(schedule['Building'] == building) & (schedule['ID'] == id)]['Dur'].values
        min_duration = min(durations)
        max_duration = max(durations)
        sum_duration = sum(durations)

        #convert duration in datetime format to seconds
        date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(duration), "%H:%M:%S")
        a_timedelta = date_time - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
        duration_in_seconds = a_timedelta.total_seconds()

        percent_time = 1.0/duration_in_seconds

        data_retrieved = [employee_name, date, building, id, num_years, employee_type, start, end, duration,
                         sum_duration, percent_time, 'NA', work_sequence_converted, min_duration, max_duration, status]

        output_data_list.append(data_retrieved)
        print('ree')

    output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data_list, columns=output_columns)


    # further computations on created df....
    # further computations on created df....
   # further computations on created df....

    output_df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)


def main():
    create_output('employees.csv', 'schedule.csv', 'out.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I ran this on a dataset with 80,000 rows and it took hours. How can I vectorize/optimize the loop with conditionals above so that I no longer iterate over the entire df?

I am completely new to pandas optimization, so any help goes a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is manually performing a "merge"

```
key_cols = ['Building', 'ID']

output_df = employee_df.merge(
    schedule.drop(columns=['Name', 'Op Date', 'Rev', 'Start Time']), 
    on=key_cols, how='outer'
)
```

You can `.drop()` whatever columns are not needed from `schedule` in your final result.

`how='outer'` will include rows that have no "match".

```
>>> output_df
   Name      Date  Building  ID Start Time Stop Time Duration  Years   EmployeeType  Status  Dur   WorkType
0     1  3/1/2021         1   1   22:04:05   0:00:00  1:55:55     21  EmployeeType1  Status  1.0  WorkType1
1     1  3/1/2021         1   1   22:04:05   0:00:00  1:55:55     21  EmployeeType1  Status  1.0  WorkType1
2     1  3/1/2021         2   2   17:04:05   0:00:00  5:55:55     21  EmployeeType1  Status  NaN        NaN
```

Now that you have a single dataframe you can `groupby` on the `key_cols` and use [Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) to generate your summary of each group.

```
summary = { column: (column, 'first') for column in employee_df.columns }
summary['%Time'] = (
    'Duration', 
    lambda dur: 
        1 / (pd.Timestamp(dur.iat[0])
               .replace(year=1900, day=1, month=1)
          - pd.Timestamp(1900, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
)
summary.update({
    'SumDuration': ('Dur', 'sum'), 
    'MinDuration': ('Dur', 'min'), 
    'MaxDuration': ('Dur', 'max'), 
    'WorkType':    ('WorkType', ','.join)
})

output_df = output_df.fillna('').groupby(key_cols).agg(**summary)
```

```
>>> output_df
             Name      Date  Building  ID Start Time Stop Time Duration  ...   EmployeeType  Status     %Time  SumDuration MinDuration MaxDuration             WorkType
Building ID                                                              ...                                                                                           
1        1      1  3/1/2021         1   1   22:04:05   0:00:00  1:55:55  ...  EmployeeType1  Status  0.000144          2.0         1.0         1.0  WorkType1,WorkType1
2        2      1  3/1/2021         2   2   17:04:05   0:00:00  5:55:55  ...  EmployeeType1  Status  0.000047
```

You can then clean it up by removing the added index, add in your `NA` strings and remove the `%Time` for the rows that have no `Dur` values.

```
output_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
output_df.replace({'': 'NA'}, inplace=True)
output_df.loc[ output_df.SumDuration == 'NA', '%Time' ] = 'NA'
```

Which produces:

```
>>> output_df.to_csv()
Name,Date,Building,ID,Start Time,Stop Time,Duration,Years,EmployeeType,Status,%Time,SumDuration,MinDuration,MaxDuration,WorkType
1,3/1/2021,1,1,22:04:05,0:00:00,1:55:55,21,EmployeeType1,Status,0.00014378145219266715,2.0,1.0,1.0,"WorkType1,WorkType1"
1,3/1/2021,2,2,17:04:05,0:00:00,5:55:55,21,EmployeeType1,Status,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

**EDIT**

---

Here is your `create_output` function written using `groupby().apply()` instead of `.agg()` - it should be easier for you to follow.

```
def create_output(employee_file, schedule_file, output_file):
    output_columns = ['Name', 'Date', 'Building', 'ID', 'Years', 'Type', 'Start Time', 'Stop Time', 'Duration',
                      'SumDuration', '%Time', 'Gap', 'Sequence', 'MinDuration', 'MaxDuration', 'Status']

    employee_df = pd.read_csv(employee_file)
    schedule = pd.read_csv(schedule_file)

    key_cols = ['Building', 'ID']

    output_df = employee_df.merge(
        schedule.drop(columns=['Name', 'Op Date', 'Rev', 'Start Time']), 
        on=key_cols, how='outer'
    )

    def summary(df):
        row = df.iloc[0]

        min_duration  = df['Dur'].min()
        max_duration  = df['Dur'].max()
        sum_duration  = df['Dur'].sum()
        work_sequence = ','.join(df['WorkType'])

        row['Type'] = row['EmployeeType']
        row['SumDuration'] = sum_duration
        row['%Time'] = ''

        if sum_duration: # only add %Time if there is a duration
            duration = row['Duration']
            date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(duration, "%H:%M:%S")
            a_timedelta = date_time - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
            duration_in_seconds = a_timedelta.total_seconds()
            percent_time = 1.0/duration_in_seconds
            row['%Time'] = percent_time

        row['Gap'] = 'NA'
        row['MinDuration'] = min_duration
        row['MaxDuration'] = max_duration
        row['Sequence'] = work_sequence

        return row.loc[output_columns] # reorder the columns

    output_df = output_df.fillna('').groupby(key_cols).apply(summary)

    output_df.replace({'': 'NA'}).to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

Comment: thanks for the response! can you explain what summary = ... summary[%Time... summer.update logic is called in python? I'm having trouble understanding how it all works

Answer (score 1):

Given your data frames like this:

```
>>df
  Name      Date Building ID  ... Duration Years   EmployeeType  Status
0    1  3/1/2021        1  1  ...  1:55:55    21  EmployeeType1  Status
1    1  3/1/2021        2  2  ...  5:55:55    21  EmployeeType1  Status

>>df2   # Schedule Data frame
  Name Rev Building ID   Op Date Start Time Dur   WorkType
0    1   1        1  1  3/1/2021   23:04:12   1  WorkType1
1    1   1        1  1  3/1/2021   23:44:00   1  WorkType1
```

I just modified your a function a bit to implement it using pandas' `apply` method.

```
def create_output(row):
    if len(list(df2.loc[(df2['Building'] == row['Building']) & (df2['ID'] ==  row['ID'])].iterrows())) == 0:
        data_retrieved = [row['Name'], row['Date'], row['Building'], row['ID'], row['Years'], row['EmployeeType'], row['Start Time'], row['Stop Time'], row['Duration'],
                          'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', row['Status']]
        return data_retrieved
    work_sequence = df2.loc[(df2['Building'] == row['Building']) & (df2['ID'] ==  row['ID'])]['WorkType'].tolist()
    work_sequence_converted = ''.join(work_sequence)
    # get all durations for this pair
    durations = df2.loc[(df2['Building'] == row['Building']) & (df2['ID'] == row['ID'])]['Dur'].astype(int).values
    min_duration = min(durations)
    max_duration = max(durations)
    sum_duration = sum(durations)
    # convert duration in datetime format to seconds
    date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row['Duration']), "%H:%M:%S")
    a_timedelta = date_time - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    duration_in_seconds = a_timedelta.total_seconds()
    percent_time = 1.0 / duration_in_seconds
    data_retrieved = [row['Name'], row['Date'], row['Building'], row['ID'], row['Years'], row['EmployeeType'], row['Start Time'], row['Stop Time'], row['Duration'],
                      sum_duration, percent_time, 'NA', work_sequence_converted, min_duration, max_duration, row['Status']]
    return data_retrieved
```

Now you can call this function for each of the rows without having to iterate manually, and since you're not iterating it manually, it is going to be extremely fast..

```
df.apply(create_output, axis=1)
0    [1, 3/1/2021, 1, 1, 21, EmployeeType1, 22:04:0...
1    [1, 3/1/2021, 2, 2, 21, EmployeeType1, 17:04:0...
dtype: object
```

Since it is a dataframe, you can easily convert it to the list,

```
df.apply(create_output, axis=1).tolist()
[['1', '3/1/2021', '1', '1', '21', 'EmployeeType1', '22:04:05', '0:00:00', '1:55:55', 2, 0.00014378145219266715, 'NA', 'WorkType1WorkType1', 1, 1, 'Status'], ['1', '3/1/2021', '2', '2', '21', 'EmployeeType1', '17:04:05', '0:00:00', '5:55:55', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'Status']]
```

Comment: I think I am following, but where are you getting df2 from in the create_output function if you aren't passing it in?

Comment: In the example, I have defined df2 before the function definition,

Comment: what you can do is, you can just define an empty dataframe as df2=pd.DataFrame() before the function definition, and you can assign the actual dataframe to df2 when you are vectorizing.

Comment: i ended up doing that. i implemented your solution but the runtime is still the same